# What's best protection for a really high voltage 50kV generator PCB?

Tags: high-voltage, protection

What is the best options for protecting a 50kV high voltage low amp PCB?
Encapsulation the components, potting the whole thing or just using conformal coating will be enough for the corona discharge?

Comment: *'sorry, i'm jsut a mech engr, has no knowledge about PCB. "* Then **don't** manipulate 50kV. It's lethal. Ask/hire a professional. No offense, but would you drive a car that was fabricated by a high skilled zoo caretaker that got its knowledge (how to build a car) from asking information on a website? Seriously, ask/hire a professional to advise you.

Comment: What are you protecting it from, or are you wanting to protect people from it?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson That's 80 V, nowhere near 50 kV. I think your PCB design should look different for 80 V and 50 kV.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Although the question is about 80V, the answers provide more general information about high-voltage PCB design.

Comment: When you say "low amp" what current are you talking about? What is the size of the installation? shoebox? room? separate building?

Comment: @Huisman thanks for the concern, and no worry. I am not the one who designing the PCB. I'm in charge of designing the enclosures and look for something that seal the high voltage area on the PCB.

Comment: @HandyHowie this thing is a voltage generator, so it only sits there...so i don't know tbh

Comment: @PeterJennings it's only about 2mA...the generator is about like shoe box size

Comment: @PeterJennings and its only has 50W max

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's dangerous and vague.

Answer (score 6):

PCB is an inadequate technology for 50 kV as your creepage distances will be like half a meter. Air is a much better insulator than any PCB surface, so you'll have to lay your circuit on a bunch of insulator pylons connected by high-voltage cables. Then you put that in an enclosed cabinet / building with a lock, and make a system tracking who is currently in possession of the keys.

Coating won't do anything at that voltage, the arc will go right through it. Potting is rarely used as it makes your system a maintenance nightmare. Mineral oil filling may be viable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @DmitryGrigoryev. but looking at the similar product, their design is only smaller than a shoe box size, I'm not sure :(